# Как сделать проверку на категорию и дочерние категории Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всего на сайте 3 главных категории, у них есть дочерние подкатегории. Цель: вывести в шапке разные лого.
Например категория 1 и ее дочерние - 1 лого
Категория 2 и дочерние - 2 лого
И 3-я так же.
Как сделать проверку когда находишься на странице категории?
Пробовал условие is_product_category, оно работает только для той категории, которую укажешь, а нужно, чтобы проверяло родительскую категорию и ее дочерние.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить что вы находитесь на странице категории вам нужно использовать ф-цию `is_product_category`. Чтобы проверить конкретную категоирию:

```
if ( is_product_category( 10 ) ) { // Эта страница для категории с id - 10.
    // Your code.
}
if ( is_product_category( 'awesome-category' ) ) { // Эта страница для категории с slug'ом - awesome-category.
    // Your code.
}
```

Теперь. Чтобы проверить, что это не только текущая категории но и дочерняя, можно использовать функцию `term_is_ancestor_of` . Для получения id текущего поста или категории используйте функцию `get_queried_object_id`:

```
if ( term_is_ancestor_of( 10, get_queried_object_id() ) ) { // Эта категория дочерняя для категории с ID - 10.
    // Your code.
}
```

И теперь все условие вместе:

```
if ( is_product_category( 10 ) || term_is_ancestor_of( 10, get_queried_object_id() ) ) {
// Your code.
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_product_category/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_is_ancestor_of/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/

Comment: is_category не работает для woocommerce, заменил на is_product_category, так же работает только для одной категории без дочерних. В каком файле нужно делать условие?

Comment: @user408302 вместо `cat_is_ancestor_of` используйте `term_is_ancestor_of(10, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat')`

Comment: @Алексей хорошее замечание, не усмотрел ночью, что о WooCoommerce речь)

Comment: term_is_ancestor_of(10, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat') работает, только как теперь объединить условие? Делаю так:if ( is_product_category(20) && term_is_ancestor_of(20, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat') ). is_product_category - при таком условии не срабатывает.

Comment: if ( ... || ... )

Comment: @user408302 Поправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо вам, вроде работает)

Comment: @user408302 галочкой отметьте вопрос, чтобы не отвлекать других участников на этот вопрос)

Comment: Еще такой вопрос. Как в условие добавить если находимся на товаре этой категории?